# Calculating MBPS - Average

Tags: networking, usage-statistics

I have found below calculation from http://www.gridsouth.com/services/colocation/basics/bandwidth
I have no idea how they came up with final number 1.395 mbps. Can you please help me with the formula used in below example?

**If your network provider bills you on average usage, let's say they sample your MBPS usage 100 times in one month (typically it would be more like every 5 minutes) and of those samples your network usage was measured as follows: 20 times: .1 MBPS, 30 times .1.5 MBPS, 30 times 1.8 MBPS, 15 times 1.9 MBPS and 5 times at 2 MBPS. If you average all these samples you would be billed at whatever the price is in your contract for 1.395 MBPS bandwidth.**

Answer (score 0):

`(20*0.1 + 30*1.5 + ... + 5*2)/100 = 1.395`

Looks like the standard definition for a (weighted) average...